# Custom color coding in Google Spreadsheet based on values

Tags: google-sheets, colors, conditional-formatting

I am looking to compare values in google spreadsheet and paint them based on value from 2 different sheets

Example cell values are:data_sheet C3|**0.536**|  D3|**0.568**|  E3|**0.527**|  F3|**0.378**|  G3|**0.498** |,

and dev_sheet E3|**0.4948240742**|  F3|**0.7823240742**|

for each cell in row 3 need to exam if C3 < E3 and C3 > F3. 
In case C3 are less then E3 paint cell C3 in Red color otherwise leave it white, 
In case C3 are greater then F3 paint cell C3 in Green color otherwise leave it white.
(none of those cases are true so C3 will stay white)

In case F3 are lower then E3 an cell F3 should be painted Red.

I am able to do nested IF statement but unable to find something where i can actually paint cells by the values. Also tried conditional formatting but unable to get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional format rules to achieve this. I suppose you haven't tried using [Custom formula is](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?visit_id=637190217121907676-733396523&rd=1#formulas). For example:

> If C3 > F3, then C3 turns green.

[image]

You can add as many rules as you want for each cell, as far as I they don't contradict each other.

I hope this helps!